# Can't Send Email Using JHipster JavaMail Office365

Tags: java, spring, email, yaml

I've been trying to set up our no-reply@company.com email to programmatically send emails for registration, resetting emails, etc. Although I have this functionality working in my local env, in our staging env for Heroku - I get an error that I cannot seem to solve.

Here is the error message that gets thrown in our Heroku environment:

```
Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; 
Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.
```

In our application.yml file, I have the following properties:

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: smtp.office365.com
    port: 587
    username: no-reply@company.com
    password: ${PASSWORD_FOR_EMAIL}
    recipient: support@provivi.com
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
      auth: true
      starttls.enable: true
      ssl.trust: smtp.office365.com
```

We use JHipster, and have the following set as the "From" properties:

```
jhipster:
  mail:
    from: no-reply@provivi.com
```

Is there something wrong with anything of my config files? I am utterly lost at what I'm doing wrong. Is there something I need to do with Office365? Any help would be great. Thanks!